# JavaFX code will compile but nothing happens when it runs

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I am working on a relatively simple JavaFX project, where the goal is to display a college logo, and text, and the background color and logo can be changed using combo boxes to select a specific sports team and color. The program was working before, but after adding the last "apply" button, the code will compile but nothing happens when it runs. There are no errors shown, and I can't seem to find anything within the code that would be causing this... maybe someone else might catch something?

Here is the code:

```
  import javafx.application.Application;
  import javafx.scene.Scene;
  import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
  import javafx.stage.Stage;
  import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
  import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
 
  import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
  import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
  import javafx.scene.text.Text;
  import javafx.scene.text.Font;
  import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
  import javafx.geometry.Pos;
  import javafx.scene.image.Image;
  import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
 
  import javafx.scene.control.Button;
  import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
  import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
  import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
 
  //for the media
  import java.io.File;
  import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
  import javafx.scene.media.Media;
  import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
  import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
  import javafx.event.EventHandler; 
  import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
  import javafx.geometry.Insets;
  import java.io.File;

  
  public class GUIProjectEWIW7 extends Application {
  public ImageView imageView;
  private ComboBox<String> imageComboBox;
  private Text displayText;
   
  @Override
   
  public void start(Stage primaryStage){
   
  //add media
  File mediaFile = new File("cheer.mp3");
  Media media = new Media(mediaFile.toURI().toString() );
  MediaPlayer cheer = new MediaPlayer(media);
   
  //create play button
  Button playButton = new Button("CHEER"); 
   
  //add listener of the playButton to play the music
  playButton.setOnAction(e -> {
  //add the actual actions when the button is pressed
  if(playButton.getText().equals("CHEER")){
  cheer.play();
  playButton.setText("STOP");
  } 
  else{
  cheer.pause();
  playButton.setText("CHEER");
  }
  });
   
  HBox hBox = new HBox(10);
  hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
  hBox.getChildren().add(playButton);
   
   
  //DEFINE SHAPES & COLORS
  Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(200, 300);
  r1.setFill(Color.DARKBLUE);
      
      
  // Create an image view
  imageView = new ImageView("rwuhawks.png");
  imageView.setFitHeight(200);
  imageView.setFitWidth(200);

   
   Text text1 = new Text("Here we go Hawks!");
   text1.setFill(Color.GOLD);
   text1.setFont(Font.font("Impact", FontWeight.BOLD, 18) );
   
   //structure of your design
   StackPane sPane = new StackPane();
   
   VBox vBox = new VBox(50); //padding
   vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
   vBox.getChildren().addAll(sPane, text1);
   
   
   //sPane2 needs to be defined before using
   StackPane sPane2 = new StackPane();
   sPane2.getChildren().add(r1); //add a node called r1 to be the first component
   sPane2.getChildren().addAll(vBox);
      
   //add GUI components (graphical user interface)
   

       //new combo box to be copied in under old box 
   ComboBox<String> borderColor = new ComboBox<>(); 
   borderColor.getItems().addAll("Select Color...","Dark Blue", "Light Blue","White");
   borderColor.setValue("Select Color...");
      
   Button applybutton = new Button ("Apply");
   applybutton.setOnAction(event -> {
   String selectedItem = borderColor.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    
   switch(selectedItem){
     
   case "Dark Blue":
   r1.setFill(Color.BLUE);
   break;
           
     
   case "Light Blue":
   r1.setFill(Color.LIGHTBLUE);
   break;
     
     
   case "White":
   r1.setFill(Color.WHITE);
   break;
   }
   });
  
  
   //3 - ComboBox
   imageComboBox = new ComboBox<>();
   imageComboBox.getItems().addAll("Select Team...", "Volleyball", "Basketball", "Rugby",   "Gymnastics", "Hockey");
   imageComboBox.setValue("Select Team...");
      
   imageView = new ImageView();
   imageView.setFitWidth(100);
   imageView.setFitHeight(100);
  
   Button imageApplyBtn = new Button ("Apply");
   imageApplyBtn.setOnAction(event ->{
   String selectedImage = imageComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
   
            
   VBox vBox2 = new VBox(20);
   vBox2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER); //alignment
   vBox2.getChildren().addAll(imageComboBox, imageApplyBtn, borderColor, applybutton);
   vBox2.getChildren().add(hBox); //add the play button
      
   //combine the graphics (sPane2) with GUI(vBox2) into a FlowPane
   FlowPane fPane = new FlowPane(20,20);
   fPane.getChildren().addAll(sPane2, vBox2);
      
   Scene scene = new Scene (fPane, 300, 400);
   primaryStage.setTitle("RWU Athletics");
   primaryStage.setScene( scene ); //set the scene on top of the stage
   primaryStage.show(); //visible
   
   }); 
   }//end of start()
   
   private void setImage() {
   String selectedImage = imageComboBox.getValue();

   // Load and set the corresponding image
   Image image = null;
   switch (selectedImage) {
   case "Volleyball":
   image = new Image("rwuvolleyball.png");
   break;
                
   case "Rugby":
   image = new Image("rwurugby.png");
   break;
                
   case "Hockey":
   image = new Image("rwuhockey.png");
   break;
                
   case "Basketball":
   image = new Image("rwubasketball.jpeg");
   break;
                
   case "Gymnastics":
   image = new Image("rwugymnastics.png");
   break;
                
   default:
   image = new Image("rwuhawks.png");
   break;
   }

   imageView.setImage(image);
   }
   
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks like this, structurally:

```
public class GUIProjectEWIW7 extends Application {

// ...

@Override
   
public void start(Stage primaryStage){

// ...

imageApplyBtn.setOnAction(event ->{
String selectedImage = imageComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
   
            
VBox vBox2 = new VBox(20);
vBox2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER); //alignment
vBox2.getChildren().addAll(imageComboBox, imageApplyBtn, borderColor, applybutton);
vBox2.getChildren().add(hBox); //add the play button
      
//combine the graphics (sPane2) with GUI(vBox2) into a FlowPane
FlowPane fPane = new FlowPane(20,20);
fPane.getChildren().addAll(sPane2, vBox2);
      
Scene scene = new Scene (fPane, 300, 400);
primaryStage.setTitle("RWU Athletics");
primaryStage.setScene( scene ); //set the scene on top of the stage
primaryStage.show(); //visible
   
}); 
}//end of start()

}
```

It is strongly recommended that you format your code in a way that makes the scope of the statements clear. If you apply standard indentation, the problem becomes immediately obvious:

```
public class GUIProjectEWIW7 extends Application {

    // ...

    @Override
       
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
    
        // ...
        
        imageApplyBtn.setOnAction(event ->{
        
            String selectedImage = imageComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
               
                        
            VBox vBox2 = new VBox(20);
            vBox2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER); //alignment
            vBox2.getChildren().addAll(imageComboBox, imageApplyBtn, borderColor, applybutton);
            vBox2.getChildren().add(hBox); //add the play button
                  
            //combine the graphics (sPane2) with GUI(vBox2) into a FlowPane
            FlowPane fPane = new FlowPane(20,20);
            fPane.getChildren().addAll(sPane2, vBox2);
                  
            Scene scene = new Scene (fPane, 300, 400);
            primaryStage.setTitle("RWU Athletics");
            primaryStage.setScene( scene ); //set the scene on top of the stage
            primaryStage.show(); //visible
        
           
        }); 
    
    }//end of start()

}
```

The call to `primaryStage.show()` is inside the event handler for `imageApplyBtn`. So the window will only be shown when the button is pressed (which is of course impossible, since the user can't press the button before the window is shown).

It's not entirely clear what code you want to execute in the event handler, but you need to move most of that code outside of the handler:

```
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // ...

        imageApplyBtn.setOnAction(event ->{
        
            String selectedImage = imageComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
               
        }); 
                        
        VBox vBox2 = new VBox(20);
        vBox2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER); //alignment
        vBox2.getChildren().addAll(imageComboBox, imageApplyBtn, borderColor, applybutton);
        vBox2.getChildren().add(hBox); //add the play button
              
        //combine the graphics (sPane2) with GUI(vBox2) into a FlowPane
        FlowPane fPane = new FlowPane(20,20);
        fPane.getChildren().addAll(sPane2, vBox2);
              
        Scene scene = new Scene (fPane, 300, 400);
        primaryStage.setTitle("RWU Athletics");
        primaryStage.setScene( scene ); //set the scene on top of the stage
        primaryStage.show(); //visible
    
       
    
    }//end of start()
```